# Filter between Custom Posts depending on meta_value

Tags: custom-post-types, filters, meta-value

I have a custom post type `annual_events` with `'meta_key' => 'school'` and a
`'meta_value' => 'primary'` or `'meta_value' => 'secondary'`.

So there are Annual Events which can belong to a Secondary School, or a Primary School.

I have a page template which outputs both, but I need a page template which shows both by default, but will allow the user to filter between Primary, Secondary or show both. Is it possible to do this one one page template? Or do I have to create a page with both or one or the other and just link?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how your code looks but this is possible :

```
if(some condition ...){
  $meta_value = "primary";
}else{
  $meta_value = "secondary";
}

$the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'meta_key' => 'school', 'meta_value' => $meta_value ) );
```

You can change `meta_value` according to kind of post you want to show your users. Above will fetch posts according to primary or secondary.

And for default users you can just run query without meta_value arg as it will fetch posts based on meta_key = school irrespective of meta_value.

This is idea how you make it working.

For some details please visit [this page](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/wordpress/custom-loop-based-on-custom-fields/) or [this](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-display-a-wordpress-post-only-if-it-has-a-specific-custom-field/) and [Wordpres codex page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters)